# Can an Azure dotnet worker with a webhost have a public URL

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-worker-roles

I have created a worker service with a host in dotnet core 3.1:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

THe worker has its own web server because of the healthcheck endpoint.

This worker is deployed to Azure App Service and ends up as a webjob there. Now, when it starts up, it also starts the web server on http://localhost:5000 (looking at the logs). However, I have no clue how this could be mapped to the appservice's public URL:
https://MYWORKER.scm.azurewebsites.net/

I did try
http://MYWORKER.scm.azurewebsites.net:5000/ but nothing is there.

Does anyone know how the worker's host can be mapped to the app service's URL or a subpath of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  Web Jobs are meant to run background tasks and are not exposed over HTTP by App Service.  I'd suggest you look at Azure Functions and Azure Container Instances.

Comment: Bummer, the Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks package was too nice to be true :(